# How can I return updates done in a stored procedure within a TransactionScope using Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, transactionscope

I have a stored procedure which I need to execute as part of a wider transaction scope using Entity Framework 4.0. Here is a quick demo of the scenario I have:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var scope = GetTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
    {
        var model = new SPUpdateTestEntities();

        var rows = model.TestTables.ToList();

        Debug.WriteLine("rows:");
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(row);
        }

        var random = new Random();

        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        var result = new string(
            Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
                        .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                        .ToArray());

        model.UpdateTestTable(rows[random.Next(rows.Count())].Id, result, random.Next());

        model.SaveChanges();

        var rowsAgain = model.TestTables.ToList();

        Debug.WriteLine("rowsAgain:");
        foreach (var row in rowsAgain)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(row);
        }

        scope.Complete();
    }
}

private TransactionScope GetTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
{
    var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
    transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = isolationLevel;
    transactionOptions.Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout;

    return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions);
}
```

The purpose of the stored procedure `UpdateTestTable` is to both insert and update records in the TestTable.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateTestTable]
    @Id AS INTEGER,
    @Text as VARCHAR(255),
    @Number AS INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TestTable(Text, Number) 
    VALUES (CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 14)

    UPDATE TestTable 
    SET Text = @Text, Number = @Number 
    WHERE Id = @Id
END
```

The behavior I am expecting is for `allRowsAgain` to contain any modifications which were made in `UpdateTestTable`. The actualy behaviour I am getting is inserted records are returned but updates to exising records are not.

I have tried the isolation levels `Serializable` (as shown), `ReadComitted`, and `ReadUncomitted` but this does not make a difference to the result as I hoped it would.

Edit:
I've added some debug statements to make the results a little clearer, this is the output:

First Run:

```
rows:
Id:2 - Number:1 - Text:Hello

rowsAgain:
Id:2 - Number:1 - Text:Hello
Id:19 - Number:1 - Text:0B22C83C-58E9-403C-96B4-FB3940E1F250
```

Second Run:

```
rows:
Id:2 - Number:2135368409 - Text:CQCXCTAY
Id:19 - Number:1 - Text:0B22C83C-58E9-403C-96B4-FB3940E1F250

rowsAgain:
Id:2 - Number:2135368409 - Text:CQCXCTAY
Id:19 - Number:1 - Text:0B22C83C-58E9-403C-96B4-FB3940E1F250
Id:20 - Number:8 - Text:D5A6684B-D140-415F-A81B-36705915FAF6
```

Thanks,
Ant

Comment: perhaps this is occurring because the transaction scope is pending the database changes until the completion of the transaction?

Comment: I suspect your probably right but I was hoping to be able to use the values before committing the transaction. Also I'm curious as to why the inserted row is available but not the update. Perhaps EF caching?

Comment: seems odd, for certain.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework opens a new connection for each request unless you explicitly open the connection yourself. Therefore, multiple connections are enlisted in a distributed transaction here. Each connection sees a different view of the data. This is an anti-pattern.

This behavior is not useful and I have requested that the team changes it. EF should integrate with TS but at the moment integration is weak.

Open the connection manually before issuing the first command.

EF ensures that for each row there is at most one .NET object. When you query a row you always get the existing object. Here, it has old values. Lesson: Don't mix EF and SQL-based DML. You need to be very careful when doing that. Use a new EF context with the old connection or use MergeOption.

Comment: Thanks for your input @usr. Could you explain why the insert would be returned but not the results of the update? I will look at manually controlling the connection.

Comment: I really doubt this is the case. Be there a transaction or not. The only exception would be if the 2nd statement fails and you not noticing the error. Make really sure that you are not misinterpreting something here. For example say `SET Number = 0/0` to test that the 2nd statement even runs and affects at least one row.

Comment: I have modified my code sample to show the exact code which is running. There are no exceptions thrown to indicate a failure of any kind.
I have added debug statements which show the contents of each collection after the first run through and then a second run. (I have a query to reset the table back to its initial state before each test.)

Comment: Modifying the SP as you suggested resulted in the as expcted "Divide by zero error encountered.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.". Promoting the update statement above the insert had the same original result (after removing the divide by zero).

Comment: OK, I have no idea then. But to be honest I didn't look at it too thoroughly. Let me know if the transaction fix that I suggested *doesn't* work and I'll take another look.

Comment: Controlling the connection manually has no impact on the results. I am manually opening the connection using `model.Connection.Open();`.

Comment: I should have read your code better. EF ensures that for each row there is at most one .NET object. When you query a row you always get the existing object. Here, it has old values. Lesson: Don't mix EF and SQL-based DML. You need to be very careful when doing that. Use a new EF context with the old connection or use MergeOption.

Comment: So because I have queried the row with Id :2 previously, I am getting a 'cached' version in the second query?

Comment: Yes but it's not a cache. Caches are not needed for correctness. This is an EF feature required for correctness. You certainly don't want to have objects with different data but same key floating around. When you write to both which changes get applied?! You can also try querying without tracking.

Comment: Selecting using `MergeOption.NoTracking` is the solution, if you update your answer I will mark it as such. Thanks!